# not enough GOT space for local GOT entries

Tags: linker, mips

Could someone give some scenarios, that can lead the linker into an error

`not enough GOT space for local GOT entries`

Answer (score 2):

GOT stands for Global Offset Table. The GOT is a 128Kbyte table of pointers to external symbols. Each link unit has its own GOT, which is used to enable the link unit to access symbols in other link units.  This is explained in more detail in chapter 16 of [See MIPS Run](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0120884216).

It would appear that the code that you are attempting to link references too many (>~32k) external symbols.

Comment: I'm a build engineer, and I don't know much about coding. I'd appreciate if you can tell me a way to "force the linker generate this error through a simple test case" As a matter of fact, contributor at binutils were looking for a simple test case - http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2013-01/msg00104.html - to provide a patch/fix for this issue.

Comment: The GOT is a table of pointers to things that are declared `extern` in a particular object file. You could write a script to generate `C` code that declares about 32,000 external symbols, and compiling and linking that causes the bug. The "See MIPS Run" book will be helpful here.

Comment: thanks. I tried, but maybe, I did something wrong, and I couldn't reproduce. Folks at sourceware seem to have made some progress. http://sourceware-org.1504.n7.nabble.com/invocation-of-mips-elf-multi-got-can-cause-not-enough-GOT-space-for-local-GOT-entries-tc218026.html  I'm leaving this link here. Hopefully if someone finds the same issue, they'll know more details.